# Is a character received by a keyboard interrupt always printed to the screen?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling

When handling a keyboard interrupt, you save the received character somewhere. Is this character always printed to the screen? If not: how do you know when you have to write the screen?

Comment: Surely you've typed a password before?

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard interrupt itself will practically never echo the character to the screen.
But the OS function that delivers characters to the application might echo such character on the screen.

Comment: So it is the job of the program to read the characters stored in the keyboard data buffer and print them to the screen?

Comment: Some OS functions will do that for you. Obviously one can always manually read from the keyboard data buffer and print to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When handling a keyboard interrupt, you save the received character in a **buffer** (which could be only 1 byte in size, or it could hold several key strokes), along with a count of how many characters are in the buffer. The simplest form is one key stroke and a flag. The interrupt handler stores the key value in the buffer and sets the flag. Your "main loop" or input handling call (whatever) sees the flag, collects the key stroke data, then clears the flag.

Don't mix two different devices in the same handler.

Comment: But when the data is received, how does the program know when to write them to the screen?

Comment: Because you write the program that way, and you write to the screen when you want it done. You might be reading the keyboard for different reasons in different places and may not always *want* the key to be displayed. The interrupt handler is a keyboard reader - nothing else. You provide an interface (as I described) to your main program. Then when you change the keyboard type, you don't have to rewrite how it is used thoughout the program: you have a driver.